# 3dsensor.launch doesn't work on hydro

Tags: kinect, turtlebot2, turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I am trying to run 3dsensor.launch file on hydro without any success. the strange thing is that the follower demo which uses 3dsensor.launch file is working good. What can be the problem? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/111576/3dsensor.launch-doesn%27t-work-on-hydro/) by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2013-12-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-12-18**:
Please add more details to "tried without success". With the given information I am unable to help you.

**Comment by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on 2013-12-21**:
Sorry I am working with turtlebot-2. my problem was that when I run the 3dsensor.launch to activate the kinect I coudn't get a DepthCloud data. I found the reason. I changed the argument (in 3dsensor.launch file) "depth_registration" to be "false" and that worked. I couldn’t see a "/scan" topic either.
I still have a question. What does the depth_registration parameter do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue is discussed here: http://answers.ros.org/question/112391/nothing-published-to-scan-under-hydro/ .
I've submitted an issue to the github repository here: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/issues/123

---

Originally posted by [nsprague](https://answers.ros.org/users/2815/nsprague/) with karma: 228 on 2014-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0